# Pass id of parent view to child view and use it in controller - ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am having a problem sending parent ID to child ID, even if I do, I want to display the child's data only of a particular parent. In my code, **List** is the parent, and **Notes** are the children. When I create a List, I have redirected to Notes Index Page (Different Controller) along with ID but in all lists, I can see the same notes. I am using TempData in NotesController to keep hold of that ID.

**List Controller:**

```
//Index
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View(db.Lists.ToList());
}
//Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ListViewModel lists)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      Lists list = new Lists();
      list.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
      list.ListName = lists.ListName;

      db.Lists.Add(list);
      db.SaveChanges();

      int? idFromView = list.Id;

      return RedirectToAction("Index", "NotesInLists", new { id = idFromView });
   }
   return View(lists);
}
```

**Notes Controller:**

```
//Index
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
   TempData["idFromView"] = id;
   return View(db.NotesInLists.ToList());
}

//Create
public ActionResult CreateWithtext()
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateWithtext(NoteTagViewModel notesInList)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      List<string> TagsList = notesInList.TagsList.Split(',').ToList();
      NotesInList note = new NotesInList();

      int tempDataId = (int)TempData["idFromView"];

       note.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
       note.ListName = notesInList.ListName;
       note.TextDescription = notesInList.TextDescription;
       note.listID = tempDataId;    

       db.NotesInLists.Add(note);
       db.SaveChanges();

       //saving tags
       foreach (var item in TagsList)
       {
          Tags tag = new Tags();
          tag.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
          tag.TagName = item;
          tag.Note_Id = note.Id;
          db.Tags.Add(tag);
       }
       db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = tempDataId });
    }
    return View(notesInList);
}
```

Here, in this NotesController, I am also saving tags and it is working fine, but the main issue is with List. Also using ViewModels but that is of no concern to me for now. If I try accessing List using

```
Lists list = new List();
```

I still am not able to check and compare that ID with that List ID, it throws an exception.

**List Model:**

```
namespace NoteBlocks.Models
{
    public class Lists
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "List Name")]
        public string ListName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Creation Date")]
        public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Updated")]
        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**List ViewModel:**

```
namespace NoteBlocks.ViewModels
{
    public class ListViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "List Name")]
        public string ListName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Creation Date")]
        public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Updated")]
        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Notes Model:**

```
namespace NoteBlocks.Models
{
    public class NotesInList
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "List Name")]
        public string ListName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Creation Date")]
        public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Last Updated")]
        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }

        public string customFile { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Enter Note Content")]
        public string TextDescription { get; set; }

        public Lists List { get; set; }
        public int listID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Notes ViewModel:**

```
namespace NoteBlocks.Models
{
    public class NoteTagViewModel
    {
        public int NoteId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "List Name")]
        public string ListName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Creation Date")]
        public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Last Updated")]
        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }

        public string customFile { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Enter Note Content")]
        public string TextDescription { get; set; }

        //multiple tags
        public string TagsList { get; set; }

        public Lists List { get; set; }

        public int ListId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Created a foreign key but it is not working.

**HTML - List Index**

```
@model IEnumerable<NoteBlocks.Models.Lists>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
    //ViewBag.Id = model.Lists.Id;
}

<h2>List</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("  Create New List", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ListName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreationDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UpdateDate)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                //using ActionLink to open list of notes for that particular List
                //and passing particular List ID from here if already created
                @Html.ActionLink(item.ListName, "Index", "NotesInLists", new { id = item.Id }, null)
                @*@TempData.Peek("tempDataId")*@
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreationDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UpdateDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
     }
</table>
```

**HTML - List Create**

```
@model NoteBlocks.Models.Lists

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>List</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ListName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ListName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ListName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreationDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreationDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreationDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UpdateDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UpdateDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UpdateDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**HTML - Notes Index**

```
@model IEnumerable<NoteBlocks.Models.NotesInList>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List Notes";
}

<h2>List Notes</h2>

<p id="buttonsInPTag">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addButton1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">@Html.ActionLink("  Create Textual Note", "CreateWithtext")</span></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addButton2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">@Html.ActionLink("  Create Note from Document", "CreateWithDoc")</span></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addButton3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">@Html.ActionLink("  Create Image Note", "CreateWithImage")</span></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addButton4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">@Html.ActionLink("  Create Audio / Video Note", "CreateWithMedia")</span></button>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ListName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreationDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UpdateDate)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ListName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreationDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UpdateDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**HTML - Notes CreateWithText**

```
@model NoteBlocks.Models.NoteTagViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Note with Text";
}

<h2>Create Note with Text</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateWithText", "NotesInLists", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ListName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ListName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ListName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TextDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <textarea cols="50" rows="12" class=form-control id="TextDescription" name="TextDescription"></textarea>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TextDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Tags", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" id="tagsField" name="tagsField" class=form-control data-role="tagsinput" />
                <input type="hidden" name="TagsList" id="TagsList" />
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document.body).on('focusout', '.bootstrap-tagsinput input', () => {
        let array = $('#tagsField').tagsinput('items');
        $("#TagsList").val(array);
      })
    </script>
}
```

I am stuck to this point. Please guide. p.s. using code first approach.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no filter applied to the query that gets notes in your Index action of notes controller.

I think adding *where* method;

> .Where(x=>x.listID == id)

will solve your problem.

```
//Index
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
   TempData["idFromView"] = id;
   return View(db.NotesInLists/*.Where(x=>x.listID == id)*/.ToList());
}
```